# C# MVC Not able to save item list from Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom `<select>` HTML statement with items. Unfortunately, upon submitting the form, the data is not pushed to the database but rather rendered as `NULL`.

Partial Code segment is as below:

```
<select name="RootCause" id="RootCause" class="form-control">

@if (Model.RequestType == "Membership" || Model.RequestType == "Membership/Registration" || Model.RequestType == "General Enquiries")
{
<option value="Collaboration tool error">Collaboration tool error</option>
<option value="Syntax system error">Syntax system error</option>
}
```

The field `RootCause` is where the values should be populated into.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove if for the test or wrap with if the whole select, not just a part

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your view-model? In particular, is the `RootCause` a writeable `string` property on the root view-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection form)
{           
  string RootCause = form["RootCause"];
  return View();
}
```

By using `FormCollection` we can easily captured the value of RootCause field.